# Is "Quinn" a good given name in English culture?

Tags: names, surnames

"Quinn" has a similar pronunciation with my Chinese given name. I wonder if it is a good choice to use "Quinn" as my English given name.

I have know that "Quinn" is from Irish culture and is mainly used as a surname. It seems a little rare in given names.

I want to know if an English native will feel it strange to hear a person with a given name "Quinn" ?

Comment: It seems a little modern in style to me, but it's a perfectly good name.

Comment: Questions about proper names aren't appropriate on this site.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly good given name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about attitudes to names, not use of English

Comment: FWIW, ["Quinn the Eskimo (The Mighty Quinn)" is a folk-rock song written by Bob Dylan and first recorded during The Basement Tapes sessions in 1967. The song was first released in January 1968 as "Mighty Quinn" by the British band Manfred Mann and became a great success.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinn_the_Eskimo_(Mighty_Quinn)) I never thought of Dylan or Manfred Mann (or indeed Anthony Quinn) as having any Irish connotations.

Comment: It's not a common name, so if you introduce yourself as Quinn some people might assume "Quin" _is_ your Chinese name. Not sure if that's a problem for you.

Comment: @konjac I wouldn't recommend it; I know some people of both genders who have it, but it's a very unusual name in English. Your real Chinese name would probably make more sense to English speakers

Comment: The US Social Security Administration has a given-names database. **Quinn** is relatively rare as a given name in the US. 1339 males born in 2009 were given the name and in 2015, over 3000 females were given the name, to cite but two years of data. https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/babyname.cgi   Apart from its being (at this time) fairly uncommon, there is nothing about that name which should prevent you from taking it.

Comment: One benefit is that 99.9% of native speakers will know how to pronounce the name **Quinn** which might not be true of your transliterated Chinese name. :) It is pronounced  [kwin]

Comment: Whether or not names should be regarded as elements of *particular languages* is an open (and probably insoluble) philosophical question.

Answer (score 2):

Quinn is unusual as a given name, but as the majority of Anglophone surnames can appear as given names it would strike a native English speaker as uncommon, but not strange.

Comment: It's a common surname; as a personal name, it's uncommon but not that unusual. In addition, it can be spelled with either a single or double N, and it can be used as a either a male or a female personal name.